# If i load the checkboxes from database, and i uncheck the checkbox after submit it is still checked

Tags: php, checkbox

The unchecking and checking after submit works if i don't use this line of code to load the data everything works. `echo ($extraServices == 'Park') ? "checked='checked'" : (($extraServices == 'Park,Electricity')  ?`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Park" <?php
echo ($extraServices == 'Park') ? "checked='checked'" : (($extraServices == 'Park,Electricity')  ? "checked='checked'" : "");
if(isset($_POST['services'])) {
    if(in_array("Park", $_POST['services'])) {
       echo "checked='checked'";
    }
}
?>> Park
```

So now if use `echo "checked='checked'";` and `echo ($extraServices == 'Park') ? "checked='checked'" : (($extraServices == 'Park,Electricity')  ? "checked='checked'" : "");`
 together. It doesn't work. So with this code it will load the data from the database on which checkbox was checked. That works. But if i uncheck a checkbox it wont be unchecked after submit. How can i solve this? I thought about a way to detect if i load this page for the first time. But then i bumped into the problem that that was for loading the page the first time EVER.

I wanted to come up with something to detect if the page loads and loads the data. After that it doesn't need to load the data from the database. But i don't know how i could do this.

I dont know what to do now, hope that someone got some idea's?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, move this code outside the attribute. Do all these tests before you output the HTML and then you will be able to see what you are doing wrong

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried but no luck, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: That is what I was intending to convey, is that a help in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to code complex `if this or that or the other` type tests as a simple piece of php rather than trying to bury the tests into some html. That becomes unmaintainable very quickly. It is also not recommended to string ternary tests together.

So create an empty variable and then fill it with the `checked=checked` if the rules say it should be checked

```
<?php
$chk = '';
// here are the rules for setting the checked attribute
if ( ($extraServices == 'Park') || ($extraServices == 'Park,Electricity') ) { 
    $chk = 'checked=checked';
}
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Park" <?php echo $chk;?> >
```

So the HTML will add `$chk` always, but if its not required, `$chk` will simply be empty :)

If I missed something this at least should set you on the right path. Post a comment below if you need anything explaining in any more detail

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this. But it still doesn't work and i think because the `$extraServices` variable is a value taken from the database. And the page needs to refresh for the result of that database variable. Or am  i wrong, i don't know? After i click submit it can't load the variable from the database right? Hope you can help me with this it's important for me. Thanks for your time! Here is on what code i tested (see next comment with code).

Comment: ```<?php
$chk = '';
if ( ($extraServices == 'Park') || ($extraServices == 'Park,Electricity') ) {
    $chk = 'checked=checkedz';
}
if(isset($_POST['services'])) {
if(in_array("Park", $_POST['services'])) {
       $chk = 'checked=checkedx';
       }
     }
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Park" <?php echo $chk; echo ",".$extraServices;
?>> Parkeren```

Comment: You do know that if a checkbox is UnChecked it is not sent to the script. So you have to base your tests on the existance of the variable in the POST array rather than its value!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean sorry. How do i fix the checkbox being checked after i uncheck it after submit? If i remove the loading data from `$extraServices` It works perfect. Only when i combine the two codes it doesn't work.

Comment: Fix it for me please i need this for my system.

Comment: If i uncheck a checked checkbox it doesn't uncheck after submit. But if i uncheck it again it DOES uncheck. Why is that?